# angular common service DRY code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dry

Lets consider the following "projects" module.

The service

```
angular.module('srvc.projects',[]).factory('Projects_fctr',function($resource){
return $resource('api/projects/:id',{id:'@_id'},{
    update: { method: 'PUT' },
     query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    create: { method: 'POST'}
    });
});
```

and the following controller

```
 Projects_fctr.query( function (data) {

    if (!data.error) {
        $scope.projects = data;
        notify({ messageTemplate: $scope.notifyMsg.ReS, classes: 'alert-success', duration: 3000});

    } else {
        notify({ messageTemplate: $scope.notifyMsg.ReE, classes: 'alert-warning'});
    }

});
```

which both work fine.

I am noticing that if I want to create a "clients" module, I have to duplicate all the above code and change the references from "projects" to "clients".

The results is having multiple "versions" of the same services/controllers, one for each module.

Is there any way to make a DRY service & controller that can be used by "whatever" module.  It would really cut down the amount of code needed.

I am also using ui-router.

any thoughts?

Comment: If you  have multiple "versions" of the same services so it is not a service!

Comment: by multiple i mean 'srvc.projects' and 'srvc.clients' and 'srvc.contacts' etc.  One service for every module.

Comment: You could handle the success/error in the service and then use a callback to send your data to the controller.